# Use sed to replace multi line values

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file called **input.bash**, the file contains the following formatted var

```
VAR_1=`cat << EOF
[
    {
        "Property_1": "1",
        "Properties": {}
    }
]
EOF
`
```

and I need to replace with

```
VAR_2=`cat << EOF
[
  {
    "new_property": "2",
        "Properties": {
          "prop": "true"
        }
  },
  {
    "new_property": "2",
    "Conf": [
      {
        "Conf": "conf_1",
        "Properties": {
          "prop_1": "1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {}
  },
]
EOF
`
```

I am trying to use a bash script with sed to do so

```
#!/bin/bash
relpace='[
  {
    "new_property": "2",
        "Properties": {
          "prop": "true"
        }
  },
  {
    "new_property": "2",
    "Conf": [
      {
        "Conf": "conf_1",
        "Properties": {
          "prop_1": "1"
        }
      }
    ],
    "Properties": {}
  },
]'


taget='[
    {
        "Property_1": "1",
        "Properties": {}
    }
]'


sed -i 's/${target}/${replace}/' input.bash
```

but I keep getting different errors.
Can someone indicate me the correct sed command to use in this scenario?

Comment: `sed` isn't a good choice for this but if you REALLY want to go down that road for some reason, add `-z` and then read [is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29613304/is-it-possible-to-escape-regex-metacharacters-reliably-with-sed).